# Remove corners when drawing thick lines

Tags: .net, gdi+

## Result:

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/TCyG2pVxi2I/AAAAAAAADSM/TTqZZxh5LR8/s800/Capture4.gif](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/TCyG2pVxi2I/AAAAAAAADSM/TTqZZxh5LR8/s800/Capture4.gif)

## Question:

Can I round or do something with this line "appendix"?

## Code:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Point[] points1 = new Point[] {
            new Point(50, 90),
            new Point(60, 20),
            new Point(70, 120)
        };

        GraphicsPath path1 = new GraphicsPath();
        path1.AddLines(points1);

        ControlPaint.DrawGrid(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle,
            new Size(10, 10), Color.Red);

        using (Pen p = Pens.DarkBlue.Clone() as Pen)
        {
            p.Width = 5;
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(p, path1);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Width: " + p.Width, 
                new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold), 
                Brushes.DarkBlue, new Point(35, 150));

            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            m.Translate(50, 0);
            e.Graphics.Transform = m;

            p.Width = 1;
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(p, path1);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, -40, 20, 150, 20);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Width: " + p.Width, 
                this.Font, Brushes.DarkBlue, new Point(35, 150));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change [`Pen.LineJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.linejoin.aspx) to [`LineJoin.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.linejoin.aspx). You can also lower [`Pen.MiterLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.miterlimit.aspx) to clip very long corners.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, this is exactly I was searching for. I used `LineJoin.Bevel;`

Comment: How do you think, what method Round or Bevel is more performant?